# WARNING in asset size limit when deploying a rails web app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack, deployment

The last deployment of my rails web app to Heroku had the build succeed however visiting the site gives the "We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information." error.

After looking at the build log I identified a warning I'd never seen before about asset size limits. Assuming this is the problem (full build log below in case it isn't) how do I fix it? I find plenty of solutions on line that require editing a file called `webpack.config.js` but rails doesn't set up that file instead using `config/webpack/*.js` files. How do I edit the `config/webpack/*.js` files to solve my problem?

````
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/ruby
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Installing bundler 2.2.21
-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.6
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.2.21
       Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
       Using rake 13.0.6
       Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
       Using i18n 1.8.10
       Using minitest 5.11.3
       Using tzinfo 2.0.4
       Using zeitwerk 2.4.2
       Using activesupport 6.1.3.2
       Using builder 3.2.4
       Using erubi 1.10.0
       Using racc 1.5.2
       Using nokogiri 1.12.3 (x86_64-linux)
       Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Using crass 1.0.6
       Using loofah 2.12.0
       Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.1
       Using actionview 6.1.3.2
       Using rack 2.2.3
       Using rack-test 1.1.0
       Using actionpack 6.1.3.2
       Using nio4r 2.5.8
       Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
       Using websocket-driver 0.7.5
       Using actioncable 6.1.3.2
       Using globalid 0.5.2
       Using activejob 6.1.3.2
       Using activemodel 6.1.3.2
       Using activerecord 6.1.3.2
       Using marcel 1.0.1
       Using mini_mime 1.0.3
       Using activestorage 6.1.3.2
       Using mail 2.7.1
       Using actionmailbox 6.1.3.2
       Using actionmailer 6.1.3.2
       Using actiontext 6.1.3.2
       Using bundler 2.2.21
       Using method_source 1.0.0
       Using thor 1.1.0
       Using railties 6.1.3.2
       Using sprockets 4.0.2
       Using sprockets-rails 3.2.2
       Using rails 6.1.3.2
       Using active_storage_validations 0.8.9
       Using execjs 2.8.1
       Using autoprefixer-rails 10.3.1.0
       Using aws-eventstream 1.1.1
       Using aws-partitions 1.490.0
       Using aws-sigv4 1.2.4
       Using jmespath 1.4.0
       Using aws-sdk-core 3.119.1
       Using aws-sdk-kms 1.46.0
       Using aws-sdk-s3 1.87.0
       Using bcrypt 3.1.13
       Using msgpack 1.4.2
       Using bootsnap 1.7.2
       Using ffi 1.15.3
       Using sassc 2.4.0
       Using bootstrap-sass 3.4.1
       Using will_paginate 3.3.0
       Using bootstrap-will_paginate 1.0.0
       Using faker 2.11.0
       Using mini_magick 4.9.5
       Using ruby-vips 2.1.3
       Using image_processing 1.9.3
       Using jbuilder 2.10.0
       Using pg 1.2.3
       Using puma 5.3.1
       Using rack-proxy 0.7.0
       Using tilt 2.0.10
       Using sassc-rails 2.1.2
       Using sass-rails 6.0.0
       Using semantic_range 3.0.0
       Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
       Using turbolinks 5.2.1
       Using webpacker 5.4.0
       Bundle complete! 31 Gemfile dependencies, 74 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups 'development' and 'test' were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
       Bundle completed (0.85s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Installing node-v12.16.2-linux-x64
-----> Installing yarn-v1.22.4
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       yarn install v1.22.4
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 21.27s.
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.234444 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/application-96e4b733b883aefe5c13e1a8aa2f1c8fc3eb2d140275f7e12823d934eebb480f.css
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.235329 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/application-96e4b733b883aefe5c13e1a8aa2f1c8fc3eb2d140275f7e12823d934eebb480f.css.gz
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.236087 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-0805fb1fe24235f70a639f67514990e4bfb6d2cfb00ca563ad4b553c240ddc33.eot
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.236346 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-0805fb1fe24235f70a639f67514990e4bfb6d2cfb00ca563ad4b553c240ddc33.eot.gz
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.236552 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-403acfcf0cbaebd1c28b404eec442cea53642644b3a73f91c5a4ab46859af772.woff2
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.236917 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-0703369a358a012c0011843ae337a8a20270c336948a8668df5cb89a8827299b.woff
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.237274 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-7c9caa5f4e16169b0129fdf93c84e85ad14d6c107eb1b0ad60b542daf01ee1f0.ttf
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.237493 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-7c9caa5f4e16169b0129fdf93c84e85ad14d6c107eb1b0ad60b542daf01ee1f0.ttf.gz
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.237693 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-22d0c88a49d7d0ebe45627143a601061a32a46a9b9afd2dc7f457436f5f15f6e.svg
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.237921 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-22d0c88a49d7d0ebe45627143a601061a32a46a9b9afd2dc7f457436f5f15f6e.svg.gz
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.246415 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/custom-96e4b733b883aefe5c13e1a8aa2f1c8fc3eb2d140275f7e12823d934eebb480f.css
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.247578 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/custom-96e4b733b883aefe5c13e1a8aa2f1c8fc3eb2d140275f7e12823d934eebb480f.css.gz
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.247983 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-0805fb1fe24235f70a639f67514990e4bfb6d2cfb00ca563ad4b553c240ddc33.eot.gz
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.248201 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-403acfcf0cbaebd1c28b404eec442cea53642644b3a73f91c5a4ab46859af772.woff2
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.248490 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-0703369a358a012c0011843ae337a8a20270c336948a8668df5cb89a8827299b.woff
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.248815 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-7c9caa5f4e16169b0129fdf93c84e85ad14d6c107eb1b0ad60b542daf01ee1f0.ttf
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.249023 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-7c9caa5f4e16169b0129fdf93c84e85ad14d6c107eb1b0ad60b542daf01ee1f0.ttf.gz
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.249244 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-22d0c88a49d7d0ebe45627143a601061a32a46a9b9afd2dc7f457436f5f15f6e.svg
       I, [2021-08-24T21:15:57.249689 #296]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1438491d/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-22d0c88a49d7d0ebe45627143a601061a32a46a9b9afd2dc7f457436f5f15f6e.svg.gz
       Compiling...
       Compiled all packs in /tmp/build_1438491d/public/packs
       Hash: 37b1f33ba3b48ca2ba23
       Version: webpack 4.46.0
       Time: 18400ms
       Built at: 08/24/2021 9:16:17 PM
                                                    Asset       Size  Chunks                                Chunk Names
                   js/application-256c993181ca0368a67d.js    301 KiB       0  [emitted] [immutable]  [big]  application
       js/application-256c993181ca0368a67d.js.LICENSE.txt  696 bytes          [emitted]                     
                js/application-256c993181ca0368a67d.js.br   62.6 KiB          [emitted]                     
                js/application-256c993181ca0368a67d.js.gz   89.9 KiB          [emitted]                     
               js/application-256c993181ca0368a67d.js.map   1.23 MiB       0  [emitted] [dev]               application
            js/application-256c993181ca0368a67d.js.map.br    197 KiB          [emitted]                     
            js/application-256c993181ca0368a67d.js.map.gz    356 KiB          [emitted]              [big]  
                                            manifest.json  364 bytes          [emitted]                     
                                         manifest.json.br  126 bytes          [emitted]                     
                                         manifest.json.gz  142 bytes          [emitted]                     
       Entrypoint application [big] = js/application-256c993181ca0368a67d.js js/application-256c993181ca0368a67d.js.map
        [39] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 552 bytes {0} [built]
        [75] ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 513 bytes {0} [built]
       [112] ./app/javascript/channels/index.js 205 bytes {0} [built]
       [113] ./app/javascript/channels sync _channel\.js$ 160 bytes {0} [built]
           + 124 hidden modules
       
       WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
       This can impact web performance.
       Assets: 
         js/application-256c993181ca0368a67d.js (301 KiB)
         js/application-256c993181ca0368a67d.js.map.gz (356 KiB)
       
       WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
       Entrypoints:
         application (301 KiB)
             js/application-256c993181ca0368a67d.js
       
       
       WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
       You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
       For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
       
       Asset precompilation completed (47.07s)
       Cleaning assets
       Running: rake assets:clean
-----> Detecting rails configuration
###### WARNING:
       You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
       
       To declare a Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
       
       ```
       ruby "2.6.6"
       ```
       
       For more information see:
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
###### WARNING:
       There is a more recent Ruby version available for you to use:
       
       2.6.8
       
       The latest version will include security and bug fixes. We always recommend
       running the latest version of your minor release.
       
       Please upgrade your Ruby version.
       
       For all available Ruby versions see:
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
###### WARNING:
       No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
       We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 100.5M
-----> Launching...
       Released v9
       https://obscure-waters-60913.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
````

Comment: Heroku has pretty good documentation on this https://help.heroku.com/KUFMEES1/my-slug-size-is-too-large-how-can-i-make-it-smaller

Comment: Actually I don't see any error in that log - it looks like it launched/released successfully. Is that the right log?

Comment: Yes it is the correct log. There aren't any errors in the build log so I don't know what is causing the problem.

Comment: Are there any errors when it serves a request?

Comment: How do I check if there are any errors when it serves a request?

Comment: `heroku logs --tail`, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Comment: Make a request and see what the log says